# UIView disappears on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to make a simple plus to check animation (`+ -> ✓`). For some reason, though, the horizontal line disappears as it rotates.

This is the code for the lines, `vertLine` and `horizLine` (they are both UIViews in a UIButton):

```
let inset = imageEdgeInsets.top
let lineWidth: CGFloat = 1

vertLine.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: lineWidth, height: frame.height - inset * 2))
vertLine.center = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
vertLine.backgroundColor = tintColor
addSubview(vertLine)

horizLine.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: frame.width - inset * 2, height: lineWidth))
horizLine.center = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 2, y: frame.height / 2)
horizLine.backgroundColor = tintColor
addSubview(horizLine)
```

This is the code to animate them (the animation is slow so I can see what's happening):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
    self.vertLine.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi * 3 / 4)
    self.vertLine.center.x = self.frame.width / 2 + self.vertLine.frame.width * 1 / 4
    self.vertLine.center.y = self.frame.height / 2

    self.horizLine.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi * 3 / 4).scaledBy(x: 0.5, y: 1)
    self.horizLine.frame.origin.x = self.vertLine.frame.origin.x - self.horizLine.frame.width
    self.horizLine.frame.origin.y = self.frame.height / 2

    print(self.horizLine.frame)
    print(self.vertLine.frame)
}
```

[This is what it looks like](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16lytAuZFCVcERmHp80Pk91RCROBAgPgw/view?usp=sharing). As you can see, `horizLine` is disappearing as it rotates.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this behavior was happening, but I found a workaround:

For some reason, the line was thinning out when I set `horizLine`'s origin. It worked just fine when I set the center instead.

If anyone knows why setting the center works whereas setting the origin does not, please do tell!